remove default conda channels
I have just re-installed my anaconda. Below is my ~/.condarc
channels:
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/r
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/msys2
custom_channels:
  conda-forge: https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud
  pytorch: https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud
show_channel_urls: true


However when I type
conda config --show channels
I get the following
channels:
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/r
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/msys2
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r

and conda config --show custom_channels
still gives me the following:
custom_channels:
  pkgs/main: https://repo.anaconda.com
  pkgs/r: https://repo.anaconda.com
  conda-forge: https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud
  pytorch: https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud

How do I remove the repo.anaconda.com channels? As my conda is still trying to download packages from the default channels. I tried
conda config --remove channels https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
but got
CondaKeyError: 'channels': value 'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main' not present in config


managed to solve this in the end.
For anyone having the same issue, run
find / -name ".condarc" 2>/dev/null

and see how many other .condarc files exist in your machine.
I ended up deleting the other .condarc files.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
